# Query access database from SQL management studio without using linked servers

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

How do I query a MS Access database directly from SQL Management Studio, without using a linked server?

Ie. something like

SELECT * FROM ["C:\Data\Accessdb.mdb"].[SomeTableInAccessDB]

Obviously this won't work but is there a away to specify the access database details within a sql query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use OPENROWSET or OPENQUERY. For example (per Microsoft's Northwind):

```
 SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
             'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\SAMPLES\Northwind.mdb';
             'admin';'',Customers)
```

Adding a linked server just allows ease of configuration, so different processes can use the connection without having to specify connection details. I don't believe a Linked Server actually adds any functionality that can't be obtained through one of the two OPEN options.

Answer (score 3):

How about [OPENROWSET()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If using 64bit server, use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` as provider:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
             'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\SAMPLES\Northwind.mdb';
             'admin';'',Customers)
```