# SELECT data records from MS ACCESS database using MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I already successfully created a link from the other workstation and I can view all the tables from MS ACCESS database. But I can't retrieve the data from the tables using simple `SELECT` Statement.

```
SELECT * FROM [192.168.1.64].default.dbo.CHECKINOUT;
```

When I execute this query i got this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.
```

I also found this query:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=192.168.1.64;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT *
      FROM default.dbo.CHECKINOUT') AS a;
GO
```

but got this error:

```
Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
Msg 1231, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1231].
```

[image: Configured Linked Server]

Comment: `Default` is a keyword. Try `[192.168.1.64].[default].dbo.CHECKINOUT`

Comment: @Igor - i got this error with your code:

`Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "192.168.1.64". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.`

Comment: I'm not following what's going on here.  SQLNCLI and SQLNCLI10 are providers for connecting to other SQL Server instances.  Normally for MS Access, you need to use the Jet 4.0 provider (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0) or the ACE provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0).  See example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583943/query-access-database-from-sql-management-studio-without-using-linked-servers).  Note that the provider takes a file path, not a network location.  How exactly is this Access database set up?  Does the workstation have another instance of SQL Server installed?

Comment: @BaconBits, the other workstation don't have SQL Server installed. And also I'm trying to access other workstation meaning the filepath would look like:

`\\192.168.1.64\C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\SAMPLES\Northwind.mdb` ?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM [192.168.1.64]...[CHECKINOUT]`

Comment: It would be like: `\\192.168.1.64\C$\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\SAMPLES\Northwind.mdb` if the account running your SQL Server Express instance has administrator access to the remote machine.  Otherwise, you'd have to create a share on the workstation.

Comment: @GordThompson, Thanks! That works! Post it as answer and will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Linked Server in SQL Server that points to an Access database we refer to a specific database file, so "catalog" and "schema" have no real meaning in that context. Therefore, when specifying an Access table as a four-part name in T-SQL we simply omit the second and third parts:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [AccessLinkedServerName]...[TableName]
```

or, in your case

```sql
SELECT * FROM [192.168.1.64]...[CHECKINOUT]
```