# MS Access JOIN Access table with SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, join, odbc

I wanted to know if it's possible to join a MS Access table with a SQLtable (in access) and whether the best method to do this is vba? (Unforunately I don't have the capability to link the databases)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible!
You have to create a linked table ,see this link for more info: [sql linked table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e#bm2)

Comment: Hi, I don't have the capability to do this as it requires an admin password and I won't be given the privileges to do so

Comment: you don't need admin privileges to do this. try to create a user ODBC connection to the sql server where  you have the db

Comment: Indeed. You can do it either way, in fact -- SQL Server [can query Access tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583943/query-access-database-from-sql-management-studio-without-using-linked-servers) -- but linking to the SQL Server table from Access is the way it's done most usually. You shouldn't need admin privileges -- if you can see the SQL Server table in some client tool yourself right now, you can probably configure Access to see it, too.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer is *yes*, the next word is *but*, because it can be painfully slow, indeed if you will have multiple joins - because Access has to pull the entire table(s) from SQL Server to perform the join(s).

So be prepared to spend some time tweaking with subqueries and - as the last option - even to upload your Access table to a temp table in SQL Server so this can handle the join (or vice versa).